# How can mod_rewrite choose the correct RewriteCond in an ElseIf logic in order to decide whether to add WWW or not?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for the following logic:

1. If the Host has only 1 dot, add www (e.g. example.com will turn to www.example.com)
2. **Else**, **if** the Host starts with www, remove it (e.g. www.dummy.example.com will turn to dummy.example.com)

I'd like to keep it general, no `example.com` inside the code.

Here's what I have so far with what I need commented out:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]  
# ElseIf  
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]  
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: The important condition for the 2nd rule is that there is "more than 2 dots" in the hostname - otherwise you'll get a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On  

# check for single dot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$  
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# ElseIf check for www and 2 or more dots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.[^.]+\..+)$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Wow, worked perfectly! Just please tell me, why did you add NE to both rules and removed QSA and NC from the second one?

Comment: `NC` is for ignore case and when you use pattern like `.*` or `^` the it doesn't make any difference. `QSA` is useful when you're modifying any query string. `NE` is for not escaping special characters if there are any in URL.

Comment: Thanks! Since you mentioned "and 2 dots", did you mean just 2 or 2+? That is, will it also work for more than 2 (e.g. foo.bar.example.com)?

Comment: If you want to match 2+ then use: `^www\.([^.]+\.[^.]+\..+)$`